# Benefits of recommended labels in kubernetes 1.12 version

Tags: kubernetes

How exactly it helps if recommended labels from kubernetes 1.12 are added in helm charts?

Comment: can you check this link https://helm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using_labels/ . it will clear your doubt.

Comment: Thanks for the information, the link has many useful information.I particularly wanted to know the advantages of using labels as below (recommended in version 1.12).                                                                                           
labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: mysql                                  
 instead of  giving it like below                                                                                              
labels:
    name: mysql

Answer (score 2):

Since this question (as revealed in the comments) is about the application-related [recommended labels](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/common-labels/) that are prefixed with `app.kubernetes.io`, the appropriate place to look is the [kubernetes documentation on this](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/common-labels/). These labels serve to identify various kubernetes objects (Pods, Services, ConfigMaps etc.) as part of a single application. Having a "common set of labels allows tools to work interoperably, describing objects in a common manner that all tools can understand". The idea is that you should be able to go into tools like the kubernetes dashboard or a monitoring tool and see a list of applications and then drill into the individual objects under the applications. However, 1.12 [was only released a month ago](https://discuss.kubernetes.io/t/k8s-1-12-release-information/1364) so it will take time for the common labels to be adopted and for tools to offer support for querying based on them. Having the labels present in helm charts is a step towards adoption.